# "Faces Configuration" appearing twice in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf

[image]

Eclipse is showing faces configuration twice in my project, how can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have two *faces-config.xml* files in your project? Are you experiencing any adverse effects as a result of the visual duplicate?

Comment: I have the faces-config.xml in my workspace in the below locations: ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Presentation\beadep\test1\Presentation\WEB-INF", "Presentation\WebContent\WEB-INF" & "Presentation\bin\WebContent\WEB-INF". I am not experiencing any adverse effects but it is a nuisance and i was wondering how to get rid of it.

Comment: i have solved it by deleting eclipse metadata and configuring the project again in my workspace